# Trying to get full course activities information for Moodle users SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, moodle

I need the help from a SQL expert. When I execute the following query I get most of the information I want, that is full completed courses by user in Moodle. The problem is when I add one course column to be shown as a result, for example c.shortname, records start being duplicated. I suppose it is due to one of my JOIN but I've tried moving them without find the problem. Thank you.

```
SELECT username, FROM_UNIXTIME(mdl_customcert_issues.timecreated, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date_created, ue.userid
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN mdl_customcert_issues ON mdl_customcert_issues.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = mdl_customcert_issues.userid
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid AND ct.contextlevel = 50
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid AND e.courseid = c.id
```

What I expect is something like:

Username | User creation date | Activity 1 completed | Activity 2 completed | Course 1 |

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Ref: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I've worked with moodle for a time, but i don't remember very well how the DB is organized. I suggest you to try and simlify your query a lot, you have too many joins. Also the user in moodle can have course activity, but not be enrolled there.